# Does django's `save()` create or update?

Tags: python, django

The documentation just says

> To save an object back to the database, call save()

That does not make it clear. Exprimenting, I found that if I include an `id`, it updates existing entry, while, if I don't, it creates a new row. Does the documentation specify what happens?

Comment: If the record already exists it updates, if not it creates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fuly documented here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert

> You may have noticed Django database objects use the same save()
>   method for creating and changing objects. Django abstracts the need to
>   use INSERT or UPDATE SQL statements. Specifically, when you call
>   save(), Django follows this algorithm:
>
> If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates
>   to True (i.e., a value other than None or the empty string), Django
>   executes an UPDATE. If the object’s primary key attribute is not set
>   or if the UPDATE didn’t update anything (e.g. if primary key is set to
>   a value that doesn’t exist in the database), Django executes an
>   INSERT. The one gotcha here is that you should be careful not to
>   specify a primary-key value explicitly when saving new objects, if you
>   cannot guarantee the primary-key value is unused. For more on this
>   nuance, see Explicitly specifying auto-primary-key values above and
>   Forcing an INSERT or UPDATE below.

As a side note: django is OSS so when in doubt you can always read the source code ;-)

Comment: This behavior looks to have changed in Django 3: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.0/#model-save-when-providing-a-default-for-the-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

This is Old, but I don't think it was answered.

when you call update() or create(), you don't need to call save() again after the fact, except if you change something else after the update call.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/.

Django basically uses the same algorithm from update() and create() in save(), so they all effect the changes directly on the Database.

Comment: but how to know which one happened

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how the `Model` object was created. If it was queried from the database, `UPDATE`. If it's a new object and has not been saved before, `INSERT`.

Comment: that does not seem to happen. I manually create an object twice, with the same id, call save, and it works. So, it seems to create on first time and update on second

Comment: It's actually a bit more complex - and fully documented FWIW.

Comment: I would reproduce like this: `m = SomeModel(**kwargs) ; m.save(); m2 = SomeModel.objects.all().first(); m2.save()`

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer this is __still__ a bit more complex - if your kwargs include an existing value for the model's PK, the first snippet will NOT create a new record but update the existing one. Once again: **this is documented** so don't try to guess, just read the doc (or the source code).

Comment: Convention in django apps is to use a primary key of integer type with autoincrement option. That is defaulted in `Model` base unless another PK is specified. If the PK convention or default is followed, the behavior is like my previous comment. Saved models have a pk which evaluates True which causes UPDATE.